# What is the difference between "amended" and "revised" clearances?

Tags: phraseology, icao-sarps

Reading the ICAO Phraseology Reference Guide I saw the term *amendment* applied to clearances, and I got a bit confused about how to differentiate it from a *revised* clearance. What does each one mean? Are there any examples?

Comment: In the US, I routinely hear "Callsign 11, I have an amendment to your clearance, advise ready to copy" and also "Callsign 11, revised clearance, advise ready to copy."  There is no practical difference that I'm aware of -- in both cases they're giving you a new clearance. There may be some term of art for the controller, but for the pilot it's same-same.  Can you link to where you're seeing the two terms used in ways that seem to imply a difference between them?

Comment: (http://www.pprune.org/airlines-airports-routes/165139-revised-departure-clearance.html) revised clearance

Comment: (http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/115.pdf) amendment clearance

Comment: ICAO Doc 9432 mentions the phrase RECLEARED, which means: "A change has been made to your last clearance and this new clearance supersedes your previous clearance or part thereof." Which exact document have you found a reference to amendment in? I can't find it in doc 9432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An amended clearance usually indicates something has been added to it, but the original content remains the same. Revised usually means the clearance has had modifications to the original content, including possible additions and deletions.

Comment: please consider registering an account, instead of creating a new one for each post

Comment: Please add the source for this information to add credibility to your answer.